# How can I used the ebay API to get every image in a listing?

Tags: python, web-scraping, e-commerce

I want to use the eBay API to get every image URL in the eBay listing. The code I have now only grabs the first image.

This is the code that I have at the moment:

```
# Extract shipping cost and images
shipping_cost = details.get("shippingOptions")[0].get("shippingCost") if details.get(
    "shippingOptions") else "N/A"

# Extract image URLs
images = [details.get("image", {}).get("imageUrl")] if details.get("image") else []
```

I just keep getting the first image instead of every image. Each image is under the same eBay URL for that listing..